# how to add object in hasMany element

Tags: grails

I have two domain class

```
class Company{
String name
....
static hasMany[product:product]
}

class  Product{
String Pname
String Qty

}
```

i am tring to add product like this

```
Company comp= Company.get(1) 
Product pdct = Product.findByPname("procut1");///procunt name is unique
comp.product.add(pdct)
comp.save(flush:true)
```

the above statement are successfully executed 
but when i try to find comp.product i got a empty list like []

i also try addTo but this give exception
so what m i missing?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the GORM methods for [addTo](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/addTo.html) and [removeFrom](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/removeFrom.html) when adding and removing members of your collection.

```
comp.product.add(pdct)
```

should be:

```
comp.addToProduct(pdct)
```

Comment: I suspect the reason for that is because you are also missing the belongsTo property on Product. If you look at the documentation you will see your mapping is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Change this as `static hasMany[products:Product]`

```
 Company comp= Company.get(1) 
 Product pdct = Product.findByPname("procut1");///procunt name is unique
 comp.addToProducts(pdct)
 comp.save(flush:true)
```

Also add `static belongsTo = [company:Company]` in your `Product` class to apply `Cascade` operations